# Y-axis values does not display correctly on my gap.boxplot in R

Tags: r

This is my script and the graph produced. I have made a gap between 7-29.8. But How can I display the y-axis values at 7 and 30? The axis only shows 1-6, instead of 0-7 , 30 as intended.

```
gap.boxplot(Km, gap=list(top=c(7,30), bottom=c(NA,NA), axis(side=2, at=c(0,29.8), labels= F)), 
            ylim=c(0,30), axis.labels=T, ylab="Km (mM)", plot=T, axe=T,
            col=c("red","blue","black"))

abline(h=seq(6.99,7.157,.001), col="white")
axis.break(2, 7.1,style="slash")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `axis` function again to plot the marks at `c(0:7,30)`

```
axis(2,c(0:7,30)
```

But because you have a gap between `7` and `30`, anything beyond `7` will have to be shifted in the plot. In general, a mark at position `y` will have to be moved downwards to `y-gap.width`, or `y-(30-7)` in your case.

So you can do this to plot your marks:

```
axis(2, labels=c(0:7,30), at=c(0:7,30-(30-7)))
```

Comment: I just tried it this way:and it still did not change... R hates me today....                                                 gap.boxplot(Km, gap=list(top=c(7,30), bottom=c(NA,NA), labels= F), 
            ylim=c(0,30),
            axis(2,c(0:7,30)),
            ylab="Km (mM)", plot=T, axe=T,
            col=c("red","blue","black"))

Comment: I actually got the 0-7 to work using the axis function. But it still doesn't want to label my axis above the gap.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to replicate the plot without example data. But I think this worth a try and should work.

```
axis(2,labels=c(0:7), at=c(0:7)) # build first gap marker '7'
```

then separately add the second gap marker

```
axis(2, labels=c(30), at=7*(1+0.01)) # the interval (0.01) could be different, test to find the best one to fit your plot
```